# DropDownListFor not respecting Selected property of SelectList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following line of code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TimeOption, new SelectList(Model.TimeOptions, "Value", "Name", (int)Model.TimeOption))
```

The drop down is properly built, and Selected is indeed correct but MVC will not draw the drop down list with the correct item selected. The markup does not output a selected attribute on an option.

The output is rendered as:

```
<option value="0">Past Day</option>
<option value="1">Past Week</option>
<option value="2">Past Month</option>
<option value="3">Past Year</option>
<option value="4">Start of Time</option>
```

Yet if you look at the attached screenshot you can see it is correctly selected:

[image: Watch list]

This affects only GET, not POST. Ideas?

Comment: can u make it more clear like whats the issue u r facing??

Comment: When you mean GET , the option value would be reset once you postback?

Comment: @RameezAhmedSayad, when the page loads (IE GET) the default value is not rendered as "selected='selected'" but on a POST, it is. There is a non-zero default value (2) set during GET.

Comment: What's the type of Model.TimeOption?

Comment: Here are the first five results from a web search on "mvc dropdownlistfor not selecting selected value": [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039006/), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278056/), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686512/), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916462/), [5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604856/). Did you try anything? :-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This tends to stump people a lot - apparently the roadmap for MVC 5 includes more intuitive DropDownList helpers.

When you do:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TimeOption ...)
```

... the HTML helper will do everything in its power *not* to use the value you set to `Selected = true` in your `SelectList`. It will:

- Try to get it from `ModelState` - which it won't get on the GET request
- Try to get it from `ViewData` - which it *will* get, because you have a `TimeOption` property on your model.

Only if both of those attempts fail, will it succumb, and use what you asked it to use.

So, in your case, it will use the current value of `TimeOption` on your model as the selected value. Which should be fine, because that's what you asked for in your `SelectList` anyway (`(int)Model.TimeOption`), right?

Wrong. Because it will *not* cast your property (`enum`?) to `int` like you do. It will convert it to a string. For an `enum` that yields the enumeration's name - e.g. `PastMonth`. If `TimeOption` is a custom class of yours, it will be the result of `ToString()`.

Then, when it doesn't find that string as one of your `<select>` values (because they're all integers), it decides not to make anything selected.

In short: `SelectListItem.Selected` has no effect on the helper. If your helper call specifies a name (either literally or through a lambda expression), the helper will use anything in `ModelState` or `ViewData` with that name, and convert it to a string.

In most cases this happens with enumerations. The easiest way to get around it is to use the enumeration's name, rather than its int representation, as the value for the `SelectListItem`.

Comment: Seems like either an oversight or a weird design decision. I assigned the integer enumeration value to ViewData, and it works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks, this saved me a lot of time. They should definitely get this working, it's pretty ghetto to have to do... ViewBag.RentFrequencies = Enums.RentFrequency.Monthly.ToDictionary().Select(x => new SelectListItem {
                Text = x.Value,
                Value = x.Key.ToString(),
                Selected = (x.Key == (int)tenant.RentFrequency)
            }).ToList();
            ViewBag.RentFrequency = (int)tenant.RentFrequency;

Comment: In my case the model property used for the selected value was "Title" (as in salutation). The same property was set in the ViewData for the page's title. Very annoying.

Comment: Has there been any explanation why the DropDown has been designed like this?

Answer (score 2):

You've already got a good explanation above as to why its not working, but just to add my 2p

Generally I prefer using an enumerable of SelectListItems as the source of dropdownitems, although either should work. It's just preferable doing it this way as there's no need to specified which item is selected - the MVC helper will infer it from the one who's Value matches the TimeOption.ToString() method.

ie

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TimeOption, ((IEnumerable<TimeOption>)Model.TimeOptions).ToList().ConvertAll(y => new SelectListItem(){Text = y.Name, Value = y.Value.ToString()})
```

NB - I'm not sure what type Model.TimeOptions is here - if its not IEnumerable< TimeOption> then replace it. (if its already a list then .ToList() is not necessary)