# In my asp.net-mvc page, why isn't the right dropdown being selected?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-select, selected, selectlistitem

I have an asp.net-mvc website and i am running into an issue where the correct selected item in a dropdown is not being selected. I have the following code on my controller action (simplified to isolate the issue):

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
 var vm = GetVM();

 var list = new List<INamed> {new NamedInfo() {Id = 1, Name = "Yes"}, new NamedInfo() {Id = 0, Name = "No"}};
 vm.YesNoList = SelectListHelper.GenerateDropdownList(vm.IncludesWeekends ? 1 : 0, list);

  return View(vm);
 }
```

and here is the definition of GenerateDropdownList

```
    public static List<SelectListItem> GenerateDropdownList<T>(int id, IEnumerable<T> list) where T : INamed
    {
        List<SelectListItem> dropdown = list.Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Selected = c.Id == id,
            Text = c.ToString(),
            Value = c.Id.ToString()
        }).ToList();

        return dropdown;
    }
```

Below is the code in my HTML view:

```
 <% = Html.DropDownList("IncludesWeekends", Model.YesNoList, new { @id = "IncludesWeekends" })%>
```

I expect No to be selected in my example (and it has Selected = true when i put a breakpoint on the server side but when i look at the html that is generated, nothing is selected:

```
<select id="IncludesWeekends" class="autoComplete1" name="IncludesWeekends">
 <option value="1">Yes</option>
 <option value="0">No</option>
 </select>
```

and "Yes" is selected by default because its teh first item.

Any suggestions on what i am doing wrong here or alternatives that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Selected` property in `SelectListItem` is mostly useless [(more about that in my answer here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691742/dropdownlistfor-not-respecting-selected-property-of-selectlist). The HTML helpers will ignore it in most cases. Instead, in your case, they will look at the values of:

- `ModelState["IncludesWeekends"]`
- `ViewData["IncludesWeekends"]`
- `Model.IncludesWeekends`

... and turn whatever value they find into a `String`, then use that as the selected value.

You have an `IncludesWeekends` property on your model, so it will do:

```
Model.IncludesWeekends.ToString()
```

... which - judging from your code - will result in True" or "False" (since it's a `bool`).

In your case, you're using `c.Id.ToString()` as the `<option>` values for your dropdown, and since the helper won't find its chosen string ("True"/"False") among those values ("1"/"0"), it won't select anything.

Ways around it:

1. (Easiest way): Accept using "True" and "False" as your `<option>` values rather than integer IDs.
2. (The almost-as-easy-but-not-very-clean way): Set `ViewData["IncludesWeekends"]` to the value you want selected (i.e., the `Id`). This works, because the helper will look at that before `Model.IncludesWeekends`.
3. Use a view model, where you have an `IncludesWeekendsId` property, then use that to generate the dropdown, rather than `IncludesWeekends`:

   `<%= Html.DropDownList("IncludesWeekendsId", Model.YesNoList) %>`

   or

   `<%= Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.IncludesWeekendsId, Model.YesNoList) %>`

   Then, when returning from the view, translate `IncludesWeekendsId` back into the proper value on your model.

In this case, I'd probably go with **1** if I wasn't in a pedantic mood. But solution **3** is a general, and mostly clean, way to solve this in cases where you have to use different values for your dropdown items than the value of your model's property converted to a string.

Answer (score 1):

Try use the Html.DropDownListFor-helper instead:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.Id, Model.YesNoList)
```

Forget about the `Selected = c.Id == id` in:

```
    List<SelectListItem> dropdown = list.Select(c => new SelectListItem
    {
        Selected = c.Id == id,
        Text = c.ToString(),
        Value = c.Id.ToString()
    }).ToList();
```

Post your viewmodel if possible.

And I would recomend using the Razor syntax if you're able to change, your views looks so much cleaner!
`<% Html.DropDown....) %>` becomes `@Html.DropDown...)`

Comment: Only problem with this is that `c.Id` in the helper isn't the same as the `c.Id` used when creating the `SelectListItem` list. It would be the `Id` of the model (if it has such a property).

Answer (score 1):

Your code would be some much cleaner if you used an enum for that
I would suggest you to use this approach instead it generates even cleaner and consistent code:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18381045/1654155

Answer (score 1):

I'd advice you to use such a type-safe construction:

```
<% = Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.IncludesWeekends, 
                          new SelectList(Model.YesNoList, "Value", "Text"), 
                          new { @id = "IncludesWeekends" })%>
```

instead of this one:

```
<% = Html.DropDownList("IncludesWeekends", 
                        Model.YesNoList, 
                        new { @id = "IncludesWeekends" })%>
```

You gain a lot - strongly typed lambda expression tied to given model property instead of property name hardcoded as a magic string. Using this construction you automatically have intelli-sense, refactoring tools and compiler support. Strongly typed helpers exists in MVC since 2.0 version, so there is no point of using older ones.

The next thing, modify `IncludesWeekends` model value to preselect desired option. In your case it means changing the type of `IncludesWeekends` to `string` instead of `bool` and assign to it value `"0"` or `"1"`. Alternatively, if you don't want to modify the type of `IncludesWeekends` add additional property to your model, e.g. `SelectedValue` and do some minor changes:

in the action:

```
vm.SelectedValue = vm.IncludesWeekends ? "1" : "0";
```

on the view:

```
Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, ...
```

You don't need to use the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` - ignore it and remove all references to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
                ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
                vm.IncludesWeekends = false;
                var list = new List<INamedInfo> { new NamedInfo() { Id = 1, Name = "Yes" }, new NamedInfo() { Id = 0, Name = "No" } };
                vm.YesNoList = GenerateDropdownList(vm.IncludesWeekends ? 1 : 0, list);
                vm.IncludesWeekendsValue = vm.IncludesWeekends ? 1 : 0;
                return View(vm);
 }


 public class ViewModel
{
        public List<SelectListItem> YesNoList { get; set; }
        public bool IncludesWeekends { get; set; }
        public int IncludesWeekendsValue { get; set; }

}

 <% = Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.IncludesWeekendsValue, Model.YesNoList, new { @id = "IncludesWeekends" })%>
```