# How To bind A dropdownlist from enum in asp.net MVC using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to bind a `Html.DropDownList` from `Enum`. Can anyone help me thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try anything? Show your code..

Comment: a simple search would have done it :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388483/how-do-you-create-a-dropdownlist-from-an-enum-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: I have done this code here you can get help from this.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380576/bind-enum-with-dropdown-and-set-selected-value-on-get-action-in-mvc-c-sharp]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public enum CityType
    {
        [Description("Select City")]
        Select = 0,

        [Description("A")]
        NewDelhi = 1,

        [Description("B")]
        Mumbai = 2,

        [Description("C")]
        Bangalore = 3,

        [Description("D")]
        Buxar = 4,

        [Description("E")]
        Jabalpur = 5
    }

IList<SelectListItem> list = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CityType)).Cast<CityType>().Select(x =>    new SelectListItem(){ 
    Text = EnumHelper.GetDescription(x), 
    Value = ((int)x).ToString()
}).ToList(); 

    int city=0; 
    if (userModel.HomeCity != null) city= (int)userModel.HomeCity;
ViewData["HomeCity"] = new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text", city);


 @Html.DropDownList("HomeCity",null,new { @style = "width:155px;", @class = "form-control" })
```