# How to get dropdown selected value in json array

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I have tried 5 different ways to get selected dropdown value but all fails.

```
// JourneyType: $("#JourneyType").find("option:selected").text(),
// JourneyType: $("#JourneyType :selected").text(),
//  JourneyType: $('#JourneyType option:selected').text(),
//   JourneyType: $("[id='JourneyType'] :selected"),
```

This journey type object is in a json array named (sof) where i want to set selected dropdown value.The json array with ajax function is something like this:

```
             <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {                 
                    $("#btnPost").click(function () {
                     var sof = {
                            EndUserIp: "192.168.10.10",
                            TokenId: $("#pageInitCounter").val(),
                            AdultCount: $("#AdultCount").val(),
                            ChildCount: $("#ChildCount").val(),
                            JourneyType: $("#JourneyType :selected").text(),                                          
                        }
                        $.ajax(
                            {
                                url: "/api/Flight/SearchFlight",
                                type: "Post",
                                contentType: "application/json",
                                data: JSON.stringify(sof),
                                success: function (result) {
                                    alert(result);
                                }
                            });        
                    });
                });
        </script>
```

The simple dropdown from which i want to get selected text value:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="DepartmentID">Journey Type</label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.JourneyType, Model.JourneyList)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JourneyType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And the model from where these values for dropdown are coming is like this:

```
   public enum JourneyType
{
    OneWay, Return, MultiStop, AdvanceSearch, SpecialReturn
}

public class SearchForFlight
{
    public SearchForFlight()
    {
        JourneyList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
    public string EndUserIp { get; set; }
    public string TokenId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> JourneyList { get; set; }

    public Enum JourneyType { get; set; }
}
```

I am using Web api Controller action method like this but everytime i am seeing null in JourneyType of sof object:

```
  public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SearchFlight([FromBody]SearchForFlight sof)
     {
 // implementation goew here
      }
```

Comment: What did u get when u run this,  JourneyType: $("#JourneyType :selected").text(),

Comment: i can see null only @sakir

Comment: try this one , @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.JourneyType, new SelectList(Model.JourneyList, "key", "value",new { @class = "form-control"})

Comment: DataBinding: 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a property with the name 'Key' error

Comment: u can try using SelectList,

Comment: in that way, its now showing any option only System.web.Mvc.SelectListItem is shown five times istead of options. as u said i tried this  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.JourneyType, new SelectList(Model.JourneyList))

Comment: dont forget add this one too new { @class = "form-control"})

Comment: ok just try this one @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.JourneyType, Model.JourneyList,new { @class = "form-control"})

Comment: still null thnks for ur try @sakir

Comment: Have you tried this: @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.JourneyType, new SelectList(Model.JourneyList, "Value" , "Text") - then do $('#JourneyType').val()

Comment: @duke: Could you tell the console output for this code `$("#JourneyType")` first?

Comment: @AmolMKulkarni I have tried this JourneyType: $("#JourneyType :selected").text() the console output is showing correct value selected however i think here value got manipulated

Answer (score 0):

Add html `id` for your `dropdownlist`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.JourneyType, Model.JourneyList, new {id = "JourneyType"} )
```

Comment: "{\"EndUserIp\":\"192.168.10.10\",\"TokenId\":\"37f5c042-6482-4492-a5e5-f0e88ccd1a4b\",
\"AdultCount\":2,\"ChildCount\":0,\"InfantCount\":0,\"DirectFlight\":false,
\"OneStopFlight\":false,\"JourneyType\":null,\"PreferedLines\":null,
\"Origin\":null,\"Destination\":null,\"FlightCabinClass\":null,\"PreferredDepartureTime\":\"\",
\"PreferredArrivalTime\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"Sources\":null}" this is the serialized json returned back

Comment: I have other properties but in ques i have omitted them

Comment: I think it's an issue with using ENUM type for the dropdown, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380576/bind-enum-with-dropdown-and-set-selected-value-on-get-action-in-mvc-c-sharp

Comment: I also think so that all this is happening due to Enum but anyways 3 hours are wasted and nothing achieved at the end @Flowerking

Comment: @Flowerking no it isn't - Enums don't cause any issue

Comment: @duke Just a debugging hint, is it still `null` when you run `$("#JourneyType :selected").text()` in browser console after adding the `id` as I suggested!