# DropDownListFor not selecting the selected item in the SelectList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor, selectlist

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC3 application and I cannot get a DropDownListFor to work with my property in a particular editor view.

My model is a `Person` and a person has a property that specifies it's "Person Type". `PersonType` is a class that contains a name/description and an ID. I can access the available `PersonType`s within the application through my static/shared class called `ApplicationSettings`.

In the Edit Template view for my `Person` I have created a `SelectList` for debugging purposes:

```
@ModelType MyNamespace.Person
@Code
    Dim pTypesSelectList As New SelectList(MyNamespace.ApplicationSettings.PersonTypes, "ID", "Name", Model.PersonType.ID)
End Code
```

I am then providing this `SelectList` as a parameter to the `DropDownListFor` that is bound to the `PersonType` property of my `Person`.

I am also printing the `Selected` property of each item in the `SelectList` for debugging purposes:

```
<div style="text-align: center; margin: 5px 0 0 0;">
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.PersonType)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(model) model.PersonType, pTypesSelectList)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.PersonType)

        <br />
        <br />
        <!-- The following is debugging code that shows the actual value-->
        @Model.Type.Name
        <br />
        @Model.Type.ID
        <br />
        <br />

        <!--This section is to show that the select list has properly selected the value-->
        @For Each pitem In pTypesSelectList
            @<div>
                @pitem.Text selected: @pitem.Selected
            </div>
        Next
    </div>
</div>
```

The view is bound to a `Person` whose `PersonType` property is "Person Type # 2" and I expect this to be selected; however the HTML output of this code looks like this:

```
<div style="text-align: center; margin: 5px 0 0 0;">
    <div>
    <label for="PersonType">PersonType</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <select id="PersonType" name="PersonType">
            <option value="7e750688-7e00-eeee-0000-007e7506887e">Default Person Type</option>
            <option value="87e5f686-990e-5151-0151-65fa7506887e">Person Type # 1</option>
            <option value="a7b91cb6-2048-4b5b-8b60-a1456ba4134a">Person Type # 2</option>
            <option value="8a147405-8725-4b53-b4b8-3541c2391ca9">Person Type # 3</option>
        </select>
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="PersonType" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <!-- The following is debugging code that shows the actual value-->
        Person Type # 2
        <br />
        a7b91cb6-2048-4b5b-8b60-a1456ba4134a
        <br />
        <br />
        <!--This section is to show that the select list has properly selected the value-->
        <div>
            Default Person Type selected: False
        </div>
        <div>
            Person Type # 1 selected: False
        </div>
        <div>
            Person Type # 2 selected: True
        </div>
        <div>
            Person Type # 3 selected: False
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the printed Selected properties for the items in the SelectList shows that the 3rd item is "Selected". But what is driving me crazy is that the option that corresponds with this is Not Selected.

Comment: Can you post the code for PersonTypes in your ApplicationSettings class?

Comment: Possibly see e.g. this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691742/ - generally, the `Selected` property in `SelectList` will be totally ignored by the HTML helpers unless there's no other option. If `DropDownListFor` can find the value by other means, it will insist on that value. In this case, it will use the value of `model.PersonType`(`.ToString()`) - but that's not what you want, judging by the `model.PersonType.ID` you pass to the `SelectList`.

Comment: The ToString method of the PersonType class returns it's name: comparing this to the ID (a Guid) is never going to match. How do I circumvent this?

Comment: Right now I am using the SelectList and a For Each loop to generate <option> elements in order to set the appropriate <option> to "selected" based on the model's property. I am manually entering the id and name for the <select> element....it all feels really unnecessary and ridiculous because the DropDownListFor method is working for me in another edit view that is bound to an even more complicated case.

Comment: One easy workaround that should work would be to set `ViewData["PersonType"] = model.PersonType.Id`. The helper looks in `ModelState` first (if it exists - i.e. on POST - when it should work already, since `ModelState["PersonType"]` will be populated with the actual selected value that was posted). Anyway, after `ModelState` it will look in `ViewData` - with `ViewData["PersonType"]` first, and only then `ViewData.Model.PersonType`. In other words, you can "override" the value on your model with the value set directly on `ViewData`.

Comment: The more general, "better practice", way to solve it (which also avoids having a custom model binder in order to translate the POST'ed `ID` back to `PersonType`) is to use a *ViewModel* instead of working with full models in your view: Have a `PersonTypeID` property instead of `PersonType`; populate it with `PersonType.ID`; use `Html.DropDownListFor(Function(model) model.PersonTypeID)` in your view; when form is POST'ed, translate the ViewModel (including `PersonTypeID` => `PersonType`) back into the actual model in your POST Action.

Comment: Thank you JimmiTH. The suggestion about using ViewData worked. I already have a custom model binder because the person object is more complicated than a name and person type :)

Comment: @JimmiTH, could you please post your comment as an answer so that I can mark it as the answer? Thank you. I also took your suggestion about creating a ViewModel because I needed to in order to get around another problem. I am trying it out now.

Comment: Sure - I mainly didn't put it as an answer because I wasn't in the mood/didn't have the time to expand on it if needed. :-)

Comment: I actually used your second solution. It is much cleaner and easier to understand. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, the `Selected` property in `SelectList` will be totally ignored by the HTML helpers unless there's no other option. If `DropDownListFor` can find the value by other means, it will *insist* on using that value.

In this case, it will use the value of `model.PersonType`(`.ToString()`) - but that's not what you want, judging by the `model.PersonType.ID` you pass to the `SelectList`.

More info in [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691742).

**Workaround**

One easy workaround that should work would be to set:

```
ViewData["PersonType"] = model.PersonType.Id.
```

The helper looks in ModelState first if it exists - i.e. on POST. This should work already, since `ModelState["PersonType"]` will be populated with the actual selected value that was posted.

After ModelState it will look in `ViewData` - with `ViewData["PersonType"]` first, and only then `ViewData.Model.PersonType`. In other words, you can "override" the value on your model with a value set directly on `ViewData`.

**Better (IMO) solution**

The more general, "better practice", way to solve it (which also avoids having a custom model binder in order to translate the POST'ed ID back to `PersonType`) is to use a ViewModel instead of working with full models in your view:

- Have a `PersonTypeID` property - instead of `PersonType`.
- Populate it with `PersonType.ID`
- use this in your view

  - VB.NET: `Html.DropDownListFor(Function(model) model.PersonTypeID)`, or
  - C#: `Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PersonTypeID)`
- When form is POST'ed, translate the ViewModel (including `PersonTypeID` => `PersonType`) back into the actual model in your POST Action.

This may seem like more work, but generally there tend to be many occasions in a project where you need more view-specific representations of your data to avoid too much inline Razor code - so translating from business objects to view models, while it may seem redundant and anti-DRY at times, tends to spare you of a lot of headaches.

Comment: The workaround setting the value in the ViewBag is what fixed it for me.     It is incredible that in 2015 this is still an issue.  Thanks for the details.

Comment: This is just completely broken.  I cannot get it to select anything at all unless the model property is of type "string".  That's useless for multi-select drop downs, because it combines everything into a comma-separated list, which is just nasty and doesn't work if your values contain commas. Broken in 2016.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your ModelState for "PersonType" key before rendering the view is empty? As JimmiTh commented is going to search for the value in the ModelState first. It happened to me too, you can try 
`@Html.DropDownList("PersonTypeFake", Function(model) model.PersonType, pTypesSelectList)` and it should select the right option.

Comment: I just checked and, yes, the ModelState["PersonType"] is empty (null); however it didn't work until I set the ViewData.