# Html.DropDownList(listname, list) doesn't return a list with a selected item

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I've recently extended some partial views to be useful in another part of my code, and in doing so, I converted my DropDownList() calls to be able to take in both a name, and the list, instead of just using the name of the list:

```
MvcHtmlString s;
MvcHtmlString s2;
var list = ViewBag.AccountCodeList as SelectList;
s = Html.DropDownList("AccountCodeList"); //old style
s2 = Html.DropDownList("AccountCodeList", list); // new style
```

However, the output from the two calls is not the same (as I expected they would be). The first call returns the string:

```
<select id="AccountCodeList" name="AccountCodeList">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">--None--</option>
    <option value="23">01L00000021150000000</option>
    <option value="40">10A00000071100000000</option>
    <option value="39">10R30129216000000000</option>
    <option value="2">2005-00-00</option>
    <option value="4">3105-00-00</option>
    <option value="5">4105-40-000</option>
    <option value="3">4250-40-12</option>
</select>
```

But the second one returns this :

```
<select id="AccountCodeList" name="AccountCodeList">
    <option value="0">--None--</option>
    <option value="23">01L00000021150000000</option>
    <option value="40">10A00000071100000000</option>
    <option value="39">10R30129216000000000</option>
    <option value="2">2005-00-00</option>
    <option value="4">3105-00-00</option>
    <option value="5">4105-40-000</option>
    <option value="3">4250-40-12</option>
</select>
```

As you can see, the lists are identical...except that the 'new' style isn't generating the 'selected' attribute.  I have verified that `list` actually does contain a `SelectListItem` which has a 'selected' property.

What am I missing?  I can't seem to figure out any reason for this unexpected (to me) behavior.

I have read this ([ASP.NET MVC dropdownlist not selecting value on render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604856/)), and didn't see anything in there that looked like it particularly applied to my situation.

#### EDIT

On a whim, I updated the s2 call to be:

```
 s2 = Html.DropDownList("test", list);
```

And now I find that the list generates with the proper selected value!!

What is going on here??

#### EDIT 2

this post seems to provide the best answer to what I'm seeing.
[ASP.NET MVC Html.DropDownList SelectedValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624828/)
it doesn't make sense to me, but I guess now I know what I have to do to work around it.

#### EDIT 3

This appears to be the actual answer to the question "why" : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20556072

Comment: Have you used both in one page?

Comment: exactly as shown, above.

Comment: So you can't use to elements with the same name, because of the same specified id! JS conflict and some problems like yours may occur!

Comment: No, Amir... I don't think you're on the right page with this..  Turns out there's a long standing bug in MVC where if the name of the object matches the name of the ViewData key, it'll kill your selection.  See the 'edit' links referenced above.  I've already re-written the code here, and its now working perfectly.

Comment: I've seen such bugs too, but found out all refers to naming conflicts. Take care about naming specially at times of working with Dynamic types(`ViewBag` & `ViewData`).